# "Hello World" in Korean

Tags: translation

I'm making a "Hello World" computer science shirt with multiple translations of the phrase "Hello World". What's the best translation for this in Korean?

Comment: What have you tried to find out this information?

Comment: It might be too late for the OP, but the most common translation (other than the transliteration "헬로, 월드!") will be "세상아, 안녕!"